# Using layer style in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, layers, style

I have a db with two schemes "public" and "versioned" (the latter generated with the fastversion plugin).
In the "public" scheme I have shp with related styles_table, in "versioned" I have other shp that always look to the styles_table in "public" schema. Everything works.
The problem is that this plugin generates versions of my shp through the views (with automatic names) and these views do not recognize the basic shp style (table_style in a "pubblic" schema).

There is a way to give at the views the styles present in the "public" schema automatically?

[image]